# Java Swing opening a new button with components in another file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I wrote the code for a basic Java Swing window and now I want to run a game in another window. The window is basically temporarily until the user hits the button. This is the code for the first window:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends Game {
    public static int height = 300;
    public static int width = 200;
    public String x = "X", y = "Y", player1, player2;
    public String[] grid;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
/*--------------------------- DECLARATIONS ----------------------------*/
        JFrame sudwin = new JFrame("Tic tac toe");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html><b>Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!</b></html>");  
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Player 1:");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Player 2:");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("<html>Enter your names in the boxes, then </br>" + "click the start button to begin!</html>");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Version 0.1");
        JTextField np1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField np2 = new JTextField();
        JButton btstart = new JButton("Start");

        sudwin.getContentPane().add(label1);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(label2);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(label3);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(label4);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(np1);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(np2);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(btstart);
        sudwin.getContentPane().add(label5);
/*--------------------------- METHODS ---------------------------------*/
        sudwin.setSize(width, height);
        sudwin.setVisible(true);
        sudwin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sudwin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sudwin.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        label1.setBounds(26, 11, 156, 14);
        label2.setBounds(10, 102, 100, 10);
        label3.setBounds(10, 144, 100, 10);
        label4.setBounds(10, 39, 172, 52);
        label5.setBounds(10, 241, 100, 14);
        np1.setBounds(10, 113, 111, 20);
        np2.setBounds(10, 156, 111, 20);
        btstart.setBounds(50, 202, 100, 28);

        btstart.addActionListener(new act1());
    }
/*--------------------------- EVENT HANDLERS ----------------------------*/
    static class act1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have 2 java files: Main.java and Game.java

Main.java has the code above, which executes perfectly and Game.Java has the Jlabels and the JFrame but it is, by default, invisible. How can I make Main.java recognise all declarations from Game.java and make it visible when clicking the button?

I'm on Windows XP, using Eclipse.

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Bound to cause problems later (or on the next machine).  Use layouts.

Comment: I'm very bad at layouts but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to have all of the fields of Game.java available to Main.java, but what you do want is a method that you can call, something like `public void setGameVisible()`. Then in your Main.java you will have an instance of Game.java, `Game game = new Game()` and then you can do `game.setGameVisible()` when the button is clicked. In this method you would have all of your logic for making the Game.java components visible.

In general you do not want to make fields public. In the general idea of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) you want to make fields from one class available to other classes through methods. E.g.

```
public class Main
{
  protected String gameName = "Super Awesome Game";

  public String getName()
  {
    return gameName;
  }
}
```

This way someone else is not able to change the String gameName, which they would be able to do if it were public. Keeping fields `protected` allows for a subclass of Main.java to still have access to those fields.

Answer (score 1):

Following from the advice Matt has given you, in you action listener, you simple want to insansiate the the new class & show the window.

```
static class act1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        other.setVisible(); // assuming we are a window of some type
    }
}
```

If the classes are in the same package, you won't need to mport it first, otherwise, don't forget to import the class first

Comment: Yup. I would be careful with instantiating it in the ActionListener, unless you are certain you always want a new instance of it (as compared to showing and hiding the same instance).